# How to return a different code for successful nginx authentication?

Tags: authentication, nginx, basic-authentication

I am learning nginx and want to know how to determine successful authentication with nginx.
With this virtual host configuration, everything works - nginx return 401 if the user or password is incorrect and 200 if it is valid.

(I know that this is HTTP, not HTTPS with TLS)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    
    server_name example.com;
    
    location / {
        auth_basic "TEST";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;        
    }
    
    location /auth/off {
        auth_basic off;
        return 200;
    }
}
```

But I want to return a different code if authentication was successful. Requests after successful authentication should receive a response with the code 204 for example. How can I achieve this?

I tried using $status but it doesn't work:

```
location / {
        auth_basic "TEST";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        if ($status != 200) {
            return 401;
        }
        return 204;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    
    server_name example.com;
    
    location / {
        auth_basic "TEST";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        try_files "" @auth_success;
    }
    
    location /auth/off {
        auth_basic off;
        return 200;
    }
    
    location @auth_success {
        return 204;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).